# SQL Server CE connection string for OleDB

Tags: connection-string, oledb, sql-server-ce-3.5

Connection string problem: I need to connect to SQL Server CE 3.5 using oledb as I want to use tabledirect function

```
Provider=Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.3.5; 
    Data Source=D:\Projects\SQLCE\AisDT.sdf;
    Password=GMT786; 
    Persist Security Info=false;
    Max Database Size=4000;
```

This is the connection string I am using to connect Visual Studio 2013 to SQL Server CE 3.5, but when I try to open the connection, I get following error:

> Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.

I have checked registry too and there is no problem in registry. I think I am missing some thing in connection string

Please check my connection string as I am new to SQL Server CE.

Comment: 'Provider=Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.3.5; Data Source=D:\Projects\SQLCE\AisDT.sdf;  ssce:database password=GMT786; ssce:Max Database Size=4000;

Comment: Done If Any One Else Needs above is the connection string with passwood and database size